# Is there a way to upgrade a theme without losing custom templates?

Tags: themes, templates, updates

I recently updated the main theme of a production site.

Unfortunately, the upgrade process deleted all our custom templates.

Is there any way I can prevent this happening again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) might be your best bet.

Comment: Yup, they look they'll do the job.